# Calculate two different value in different rows

Tags: sql

To calculate the total, start with the sum of the values in the first row. Then, depending on the value in the second row's FirstValue column, either add it to the previous total or subtract it from the previous total.

```
Date        FirstValue   SecondValue     (New Column)
2017-06-01  312500.00     0.00            312,000
2017-06-03  0.00          300000.00       12,500
2017-06-04  400000.00     0.00            412,500
2017-06-04  1600000.00    0.00            2,012,500
2017-06-07  0.00          200000.00       1,812,500
2017-06-15  0.00          500000.00       1,312,500

Last Value is   1,312,500
```

as I mentioned in a picture

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results (as text in the question), and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @ jarlh just wanted to know that dbms or rdbms ? that you said, i think it should be rdbms

Comment: @BunkerBoy DBMS is the correct term.  OP's DBMS may well also be an RDBMS, but it may not be.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column which is the 0-SecondValue, then your desired answer is a runningtotal of firstValue+inverseSecondValue